# hash::make() performs differently in different controller for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hash, eloquent

I am using `hash::make()` function in laravel when i am  inserting in user table it adds hash key for password in user table.
after than when i login using `hash::check()` function it return false.

```
$data = ['Password' => Hash::make($this->request->get('Password'))];
$user = User::create($data);
```

[image]
when i update password column for specific row using same function `hash::make()` it update password hash key.
Then it login again it login successfully.
Create:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->Password = Hash::make($request->get('Password'));
$user->save();
```

For Authenticate:

```
Hash::check($request->get('Password'), $user->Password)
```

Length for password column in db is more than 60+.
can anyone suggest something for this behavior?

Comment: And before updating it works?

Comment: no before update its not working

Comment: First you have to consider where the problem occures. Is it the hash function or is it the DB storage? First check if the hash function works: `dd(Hash::check('12345', Hash::make('12345')));` The output should be `true`.

Comment: i have test this scenario also its returns true, but after creating user in user table then i get hash key and using this function again it return false.

Comment: Is `Password` mass-assignable? In the second row you are creating an user and the password is not passed explicitly like in your update function. Could you show the code of your `User.php` entity?

Comment: Why are you using Hash:: anyway?? you can just use `bcrypt` now...

Comment: Is the `Password` attribute inside the`$fillable` array? Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: yes it is in $fillable

Comment: @Hu7sy, I have provided an answer for you written somewhat differently but its fully functional and works as it should.

Comment: i have update my answer also add screens shot for better understanding to insertion